# Invoking dotnet assembly method from C++ returns error COR_E_SAFEARRAYTYPEMISMATCH

Tags: c++, .net, invoke

I am trying to load and execute a dotnet executable from a memory buffer inside my C++ program.

In order do this, I am trying to invoke the Main function of a dotnet assembly I have loaded inside my C++ project.

First I load the CRL runtime, gets loaded ok.

Then I load the dotnet.exe from a memory buffer, it gets loaded ok.

Then I would like to start it, by Invoking its Main function.

At that point, the Invoke_3 function returns COR_E_SAFEARRAYTYPEMISMATCH.
Which I don't understand why, since I retrieved the parameters using the GetParameters function, which fills the SAFEARRAY to pass to the Invoke function.
Anybody knows what is wrong in that parameters?
Thank you in advance!

```
// Up here we correctly load the CRL runtime

// Load up our dotnet file inside a std::string
string sFileData = FileToString("C:\\dotnet.exe");

// Copy our file data inside a SAFEARRAY
SAFEARRAYBOUND bounds = { sFileData.size(), 0 };
SAFEARRAY *pSA = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, &bounds);
void* data;
HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(pSA, &data);
CopyMemory(data, sFileData.c_str(), sFileData.size());
hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(pSA);

if (pSA)
{ 
    // Load our managed assembly:
    _AssemblyPtr spAssembly = nullptr;
    hr = spAppDomain->Load_3(pSA, &spAssembly);

    // Get the entrypoint of the assembly, which should be the "Main" function
    _MethodInfoPtr entryp;
    hr = spAssembly->get_EntryPoint(&entryp);

    // Get the parameters of the entrypoint function and save them in a SAFEARRAY
    SAFEARRAY *pArrParams;
    hr = entryp->GetParameters(&pArrParams);

    // Call the entrypoint passing parameters in the SAFEARRAY.
    // Returns error COR_E_SAFEARRAYTYPEMISMATCH
    VARIANT retval;
    hr = entryp->Invoke_3(_variant_t(), pArrParams, &retval);
}
```

Comment: A Main() method normally has a string[] argument.  You don't pass an array of strings, passing ParameterInfo[] is of course doomed to fail.  You need a safe array of BSTR.

Comment: But, shouldn't the entryp->GetParameters(&pArrParams) function automatically fill the SAFEARRAY with the correct parameters of the entryp method that we will invoke later?
What about if the dotnet Main function has different parameters instead?
Thanks

Comment: It tells you about the *type* of the arguments.  If it isn't string[] then you ought to complain.  Well, no need to help as you found out.  Passing the *value* of the arguments is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [framework source for `SafeArrayTypeMismatchException`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/SafeArrayTypeMismatchException.cs) (which maps to `COR_E_SAFEARRAYTYPEMISMATCH`):

> This exception is thrown when the runtime type of an array is different than the safe array sub type specified in the metadata.

Hence I'm pretty sure this is the problem:

```
SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, &bounds);
```

`VT_UI1` is a 1-byte unsigned integer. But the standard `Main()` method in C# applications takes an array of 4-byte signed integers. These are different types, hence the error. So you'll need to change your code to this:

```
SafeArrayCreate(VT_I4, 1, &bounds);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, that function is not used in the Invoke function. That array is used in the 
'hr = spAppDomain->Load_3(pSA, &spAssembly);' function, which loads the assembly fine.
The Invoke_3 function which returns the error instead uses the SAFEARRAY filled by entryp->GetParameters(&pArrParams);
I tried to change it anyway to see if there was some difference, but if I use VT_I4 the Load_3 function will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
VARIANT ret;
VARIANT obj;
SAFEARRAY *args = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1);

ZeroMemory(&ret, sizeof(VARIANT));
ZeroMemory(&obj, sizeof(VARIANT));
obj.vt = VT_NULL;

hr = entryp->Invoke_3(obj, args, &ret);
```

change the type from VT_UI1 to VT_VARIANT.